# Externalize properties and logback Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring (without spring-boot). I want to build standalone application that can be run with default configuration (`logback.xml` and `application.properties` in resource folder) or with `-Dconfig.folder=/path/to/custom/external/directory`
(`logback.xml` and `application.properties` in /path/to/custom/external/directory). When application will be run with -Dconfig.folder param `AppConfig` should load both logback and properties from external directory.

Is there anyway to make external folder act like a resource folder?

If not, what is a common solution for this?

My current implementation (using default resource folder only):

**App.java**

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);

        SampleAction p = context.getBean(SampleAction.class);
        p.performTask();
    }
}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

**SampleAction.java**

```
@Component
public class SampleAction {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Value("${sample.prop}")
    private String sampleProp;

    public void performTask(){
        logger.debug(sampleProp);
    }
}
```

**logback.xml** and **application.properties** are not relevant to the problem

Comment: I added a comment day ago about what I'm missing :) Basically, I dont know where to put that Java code InputStream configuration to let my logback configuration be avaiable asap

Comment: See my edit. If you know nothing of Spring, you need to do your homework first. We try to help you when you've a particular problem, we don't do your job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the other answer suggests, if you use `file` prefix in `@PropertySource`, you're screwed because it won't be able to load the default `application.properties` from the jar. What you should do is the following:

```
@PropertySource("${config.folder:'classpath:'}/application.properties")
public class AppConfig
```

For `logback.xml`:

```
@Value("${config.folder}:")
private String configFolder;

InputStream = Optional.of(new ClassPathResource(configFolder + "/logback.xml"))
    .filter(r -> r.exists())
    .orElse(new ClassPathResource("classpath:/logback.xml"))
    .getInputStream();
```

In both cases, I gave preference to the command line argument over the default packaged files. Of course, I didn't compile the above, so there may be typos or minor errors, but you get the idea.

**Edit**:

Since OP claims to not understand where to run the above code -

```
public class AppConfig {
    @PostConstruct
    void init() {
        // init logback here
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder where I should put this logback configuration to: 1. use correct logging options asap 2. keep my application clean in term of split logic and configuration. Any advices?

Comment: @ilovkatie `src/main/resources`

Comment: I meant that InputStream logback configuration :>

Answer (score 0):

For log4j.xml

`-Dlog4j.configuration=C:\neon\log4j.xml` as VM argument

In main() method:

```
String filename = System.getProperty("log4j.configuration");
DOMConfigurator.configure(filename);
```

For external properties file:

`-Dext.prop.dir=C:\neon` as VM argument

Change in your AppConfig class will be like

```
@PropertySource("file:///${ext.prop.dir}/application.properties")
public class AppConfig{
}
```

Run App class with VM arguments as below and both file will be use from external location

```
-Dlog4j.configuration=C:\neon\log4j.xml -Dext.prop.dir=C:\neon
```